# Слайдер открывает все фото которые есть на странице как исправить?

Tags: javascript

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  };
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="first_slider">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/1/">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/2/">
  <button class="w3-button w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(+1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
<div class="second_slider">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/3/">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/4/">
  <button class="w3-button w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(+1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Использую на странице несколько слайдеров. Но фото 1 слайдера можно посмотреть в 2 слайдере и наоборот. Я попытался ограничить количество фото которые открывает слайдер до 2, но не получается. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Сделайте воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Как это сделать?

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, там есть кнопка "Фрагмент кода...." в нем вы сможете сделать пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае можно использовать передачу контейнера, что бы разграничить поиск слайдов в конкретном слайдере.

Но по хорошему, ваш код надо переписать, что бы он использовал объектный подход.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs('.first_slider', slideIndex);
showDivs('.second_slider', slideIndex);

function plusDivs(container, n) {
  showDivs(container, slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(container, n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(container + " .mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  };
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="first_slider">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/1/">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/2/">
  <button class="w3-button w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs('.first_slider',-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs('.first_slider',+1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
<div class="second_slider">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/3/">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/4/">
  <button class="w3-button w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs('.second_slider', -1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs('.second_slider',+1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Можно сделать вот таким образом  - ООП подход.

```js
function Slider(selector) {
  this.slideIndex = 0;
  this.selector = selector;
  this.container = document.querySelector(this.selector);
  this.goto(this.slideIndex);
  const nextBtn = this.container.querySelector('*[data-direction="next"]');
  nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.next();
  });
  const prevBtn = this.container.querySelector('*[data-direction="prev"]');;
  prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.previous();
  });
}

Slider.prototype.next = function() {
  this.goto(++this.slideIndex);
}

Slider.prototype.previous = function() {
  this.goto(--this.slideIndex);
}

Slider.prototype.goto = function(index) {
  const x = this.container.querySelectorAll(".mySlides");
  this.slideIndex = index;
  if (this.slideIndex >= x.length) {
    this.slideIndex = 0
  }
  if (this.slideIndex < 0) {
    this.slideIndex = x.length - 1;
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[this.slideIndex].style.display = "block";
}

const slider1 = new Slider('.first_slider');
const slider2 = new Slider('.second_slider');
```

```html
<div class="first_slider">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/1/">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/2/">
  <button data-direction="prev" class="w3-button w3-display-left">&#10094;</button>
  <button data-direction="next" class="w3-button w3-display-right">&#10095;</button>
</div>
<div class="second_slider">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/3/">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/4/">
  <button data-direction="prev" class="w3-button w3-display-left">&#10094;</button>
  <button data-direction="next" class="w3-button w3-display-right">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```